Drawing on QPixmap gives results different than drawing on QPainter directly
I'm struggling with using the QGraphicsItem paint method to use a qpixmap as cache on which I draw a path and at the end of paint method I use painter.drawPixmap(cache_pixmap)
but I get weird rendering
it doesn't show the lines I drawn on the qpixmap using drawPath.
def paint(self, p, opt, widget):

    self.cachePixmap = QPixmap(1000, 100)
    self.cachePixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor('black'))  # Fill with black background

    # Ensure there's data to paint
    if self.xData is None or len(self.xData) == 0 or self.x_data is None:
        return

    aa = self.opts['antialias']
    cache_painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.cachePixmap)
    cache_painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing, aa)

    for start, end, color in self.ranges:
        if color == 0:
            continue
        if start > 0:
            start -= 1
        path = arrayToQPath(self.x_data[start:end], self.y_data[start:end], connect='all', finiteCheck=False)
        pen = QPen(QColor('white'))
        pen.setWidth(1)
        cache_painter.setPen(pen)
        cache_painter.drawPath(path)

    cache_painter.end()

    p.drawPixmap(self.boundingRect(), self.cachePixmap, QRect(0, 0, 1000, 100))

 def boundingRect(self):
        if self._boundingRect is None:
            self._boundingRect = self.viewRect()
        return self._boundingRect

this code is an overwritten paint method of QGraphicsItem
when I draw directly to p the path (is a curve) shows up, but when I use QPixmap, the rendering is weird like in this picture
actually I'm overwritten pyqtgraph PlotCurveItem which itself inherits from QGraphicsItem paint method
I'm really stuck with this, any help would be appreciated, thank uuuuu
5/26/2024: update with minimal working example:
import sys
import numpy as np
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QPen, QColor
from pyqtgraph import PlotCurveItem, PlotItem, ViewBox, AxisItem, mkPen, arrayToQPath, functions as fn, GraphicsView, mkColor


class DataCurve(PlotCurveItem):
    """Graphics-Object for single data curve."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cachePixmap = None
        self.x_data = None
        self.indices = None
        self.y_data = None
        self.opts = {
            'pen': mkPen('w'),
            'shadowPen': None,
            'antialias': False
        }
        self.ranges = []

    def setData(self, *args, **kargs):
        self.updateData(*args, **kargs)

    def updateData(self, *args, **kargs):
        if len(args) == 1:
            kargs['y'] = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 2:
            kargs['x'] = args[0]
            kargs['y'] = args[1]

        if 'y' not in kargs or kargs['y'] is None:
            kargs['y'] = np.array([])
        if 'x' not in kargs or kargs['x'] is None:
            kargs['x'] = np.arange(len(kargs['y']))
        if 'ranges' in kargs:
            self.ranges = kargs['ranges']
        if 'indices' in kargs:
            self.indices = kargs['indices']
        if 'antialias' in kargs:
            self.opts['antialias'] = kargs['antialias']

        self.yData = kargs['y'].view(np.ndarray)
        self.xData = kargs['x'].view(np.ndarray)

        self.update()

    def paint(self, p, opt, widget):
        rect = self.boundingRect()

        if self.cachePixmap is None:
            self.cachePixmap = QPixmap(int(rect.width()), int(rect.height()))
            self.cachePixmap.fill(QColor('black'))

        if self.xData is None or len(self.xData) == 0 or self.yData is None:
            return

        aa = self.opts['antialias']
        cache_painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.cachePixmap)
        cache_painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing, aa)


        path = arrayToQPath(self.xData, self.yData, connect='all', finiteCheck=False)
        pen = self.opts['pen']
        cache_painter.setPen(pen)
        cache_painter.drawPath(path)

        cache_painter.end()
        p.drawPixmap(rect, self.cachePixmap, QRectF(0, 0, self.cachePixmap.width(), self.cachePixmap.height()))

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.viewRect()


class CustomViewBox(ViewBox):
    def __init__(self, plot):
        super().__init__(invertY=True)
        self.enableAutoRange(enable=False, x=False, y=False)
        self.plot = plot

    def wheelEvent(self, ev, axis=None):
        """Reimplement to do something on wheel."""
        pass

    def mouseClickEvent(self, ev):
        """Reimplement to do something on mouse-click."""
        pass

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev, axis=None):
        """Reimplement to do something on mouse-drag."""
        pass


class PlotWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self._view = GraphicsView(useOpenGL=False, background=mkColor('black'))
        self.layout.addWidget(self._view)

        self._view_box = CustomViewBox(self)
        self._channel_axis = AxisItem(pen=mkPen(color='#262C30', width=1), orientation='left')
        self._channel_axis.setPen(mkPen(color='#262C30', width=1))

        self._plot_item = PlotItem(viewBox=self._view_box, axisItems={'left': self._channel_axis})
        self._view.setCentralWidget(self._plot_item)

        self.curve = DataCurve()
        self._plot_item.addItem(self.curve)

        # Adding test data
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        y = np.sin(x)
        ranges = [(0, 50, 1), (50, 100, 1)]
        self.curve.setData(x=x, y=y, ranges=ranges, antialias=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    plot_widget = PlotWidget()
    plot_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Please bear with me that this minimal reproducible  example doesn't reflect the real use of cachePixmap. in the original code it's used to paint new incoming data without reinitializing cachePixmap each time inside paint method, it will be initialized once and each time we paint the area that will be redrawn with transparent color and then draw over it and  I pass the the cachePixmap to be repainted using drawPixmap. with this approach I avoid unnecessary calculations of the path to be drawn, to optimize CPU usage, since I'm plotting many curves in the scene.
PS: this what I get when I use drawPixmap in the minimal example:

and that's what I get when I draw on painter:

here is a new minimal example that make use of QPicture instead of QPixmap, and I try to simulate the logic of drawing new incoming data using a counter, unfortunately this only draw new data and doesn't keep the old drawn data, what am I doing wrong again?
import sys
import numpy as np
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import QRectF
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QPen, QColor
from pyqtgraph import PlotCurveItem, PlotItem, ViewBox, AxisItem, mkPen, arrayToQPath, functions as fn, GraphicsView, mkColor


class DataCurve(PlotCurveItem):
    """Graphics-Object for single data curve."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cachePicture = None
        self.counter = 1
        self.x_data = None
        self.indices = None
        self.y_data = None
        self.opts = {
            'pen': mkPen('w'),
            'shadowPen': None,
            'antialias': False
        }
        self.ranges = []

    def setData(self, *args, **kargs):
        self.updateData(*args, **kargs)

    def updateData(self, *args, **kargs):
        if len(args) == 1:
            kargs['y'] = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 2:
            kargs['x'] = args[0]
            kargs['y'] = args[1]

        if 'y' not in kargs or kargs['y'] is None:
            kargs['y'] = np.array([])
        if 'x' not in kargs or kargs['x'] is None:
            kargs['x'] = np.arange(len(kargs['y']))
        if 'ranges' in kargs:
            self.ranges = kargs['ranges']
        if 'indices' in kargs:
            self.indices = kargs['indices']
        if 'antialias' in kargs:
            self.opts['antialias'] = kargs['antialias']

        self.yData = kargs['y'].view(np.ndarray)
        self.xData = kargs['x'].view(np.ndarray)

        self.update()

    def paint(self, p, opt, widget):
        rect = self.boundingRect()

        if self.cachePicture is None:
            self.cachePicture = QPicture()

        if self.xData is None or len(self.xData) == 0 or self.yData is None:
            return

        aa = self.opts['antialias']
        cache_painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.cachePicture)
        cache_painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing, aa)


        path = arrayToQPath(self.xData[:16 * self.counter], self.yData[:16 * self.counter], connect='all', finiteCheck=False)
        pen = self.opts['pen']
        cache_painter.setPen(pen)
        cache_painter.drawPath(path)

        cache_painter.end()
        p.drawPixmap(rect, self.cachePixmap, QRectF(0, 0, self.cachePixmap.width(), self.cachePixmap.height()))
        if self.counter *16 > len(self.xData):
            self.counter = 1

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.viewRect()


class CustomViewBox(ViewBox):
    def __init__(self, plot):
        super().__init__(invertY=True)
        self.enableAutoRange(enable=False, x=False, y=False)
        self.plot = plot

    def wheelEvent(self, ev, axis=None):
        """Reimplement to do something on wheel."""
        pass

    def mouseClickEvent(self, ev):
        """Reimplement to do something on mouse-click."""
        pass

    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev, axis=None):
        """Reimplement to do something on mouse-drag."""
        pass


class PlotWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self._view = GraphicsView(useOpenGL=False, background=mkColor('black'))
        self.layout.addWidget(self._view)

        self._view_box = CustomViewBox(self)
        self._channel_axis = AxisItem(pen=mkPen(color='#262C30', width=1), orientation='left')
        self._channel_axis.setPen(mkPen(color='#262C30', width=1))

        self._plot_item = PlotItem(viewBox=self._view_box, axisItems={'left': self._channel_axis})
        self._view.setCentralWidget(self._plot_item)

        self.curve = DataCurve()
        self._plot_item.addItem(self.curve)

        # Adding test data
        x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
        y = np.sin(x)
        ranges = [(0, 50, 1), (50, 100, 1)]
        self.curve.setData(x=x, y=y, ranges=ranges, antialias=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    plot_widget = PlotWidget()
    plot_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


What is the point of a "cache pixmap" if you draw it every time, and then draw it anyway with the scene painter? In any case, please provide a proper [mre].

I tried to make that paint method simple, but actually I was initializing the cache pixmap once and keep drawing new path to it. I will try to make a MRE

@musicamante I've added a minimal reproducible example, sorry about not including that at first.

drawing into an image isn't same subsystem  as rendering on screen (it might be, but not all capabilities are possible). On anything native that even might be slower, but python obliges to compensate

@Swift-FridayPie what's the difference between drawing on Pixmap and a painter directly? Also pixmap is used to render off-screen and it's the optimal way to draw on screen rather than drawing on QImage.  also I've heard that on linux qpixmap is hosted on the server in case of Xorg.

@pourjour no, it's not used to draw off-screen by Qt. plus in modern X11 it is a software-only fallback. QPainter is not a "direct" rendering either, it already includes caching. plus Qt's pixmap api is not what is used in X11, it's an abstraction that can work everywhere.

@Swift-FridayPie hmm, can you please share some resources about that?  I'm interested in learning furthermore about qt rendering

it looks like you have mismatch of color space between screen system and default format of pixmap (there are more parameters to it). You don't have transparency either, so mentioning it is confusing

their own site? Usually qt uses OpenGL but it's done via bridge through subsystem QPainter is a public interface for. Rendering system caches what underlying widgets draw to support transparency, etc.

@pourjour It seems you're confusing the term pixmap as a standard "format". In reality, it's a generic term used for anything representing a map of pixels. How that is actually done depends on the implementation, and QPixmap is their way of doing it, which is cross platform and has nothing to do with those used in X. Also, due to the nature of QGraphicsItems (which use logical units), using a pixmap to cache contents of an item is a terrible idea. If you need some form of optimization that avoids the python bottle neck, use QPicture instead, which can be used as a sort of "QPainter macro".

@pourjour That is also what most pyqtgraph items do, and you should follow that approach too. Note that, despite your update, your "cache" is still completely pointless if done as shown, since you're constantly drawing on the pixmap and drawing that pixmap on the scene: in reality, your attempt at "optimization" does exactly the opposite, as it's even slower than directly drawing on the scene.

@musicamante yeah, the example looks useless as I mentioned it doesn't show how to use QPixmap to cache, I removed that code for simplicity. I tried QPicture I think it showed something, but I'm doing something wrong like I can't reuse it to draw new parts of the curves but it works if I keep creating new instance of QPicture each time inside paint method; which is not what I want to do to cache old parts of the curve.

@Swift-FridayPie, OpenGL is used with QOpenGlWidget, only when its forced to, I'm making this code to work on a machine without GPU, and using OpenGL make things slow on non GPU machines.

OpenGL is used whenever availablle, that widget is just an adapter (very ineficcient) for it. Qt4 used separate rendering for QGLWidget and for others. what kind of "non-GPU"? Without X11? Does Qt still support FB , I'm not sure. Anyway, check what are current color format for pixmap and for grapgical system, they must match. They don't match automatically. Mismatch may cause lots of issues because conversion procedures, scaling and etc. are very primitive

@musicamante @Swift-FridayPie  I will give qpixmap another try by checking the color format thing you mentioned.  anyway I've added to the question another example which uses QPicture as a rendering device, and it works but somehow in that example it doesn't keep what's already drawn, and that's the idea about the whole caching thing I'm thinking of. but surely I'm doing something wrong.

@pourjour 1. you cannot use QPixmap for this because, as also explained above, it's a map of pixels: graphics items are not suited for that and it's even less for pyqtgraph items (check the size of the pixmap); 2. your latest code is not reproducible, since you're using drawPixmap() on self.cachePixmap, which doesn't exist; 3. you seem to confuse the difference between cache and store; the data should be persistent, and eventually updated; 4. as the QPicture docs explain, QPainter commands are reset at each QPainter.begin(target) call (including the implicit QPainter(target).

@pourjour Please study the documentation more carefully, and eventually provide a proper [mre], which you should check on your own before posting.
